# how to update table in sqflite with flutter

Tags: flutter, sql-update, sqflite

when I try to update a table with id nothing won't happen. I got no error and I have no idea why this happens. 
at first, I try to get all data from fields, and then if all fields have value then make the User object and pass into the method for the update table.
I got id from the previous screen and other data from fields. 
as I check I have all data inside the validate method in CompleteUserInformationScreen and I think error occur somewhere when I try to call update method with sqflite.

this is my method for the update table:

```
 Future<User> update(User user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    // return await dbClient.update(USER_TABLE, user.toMap(),
    //     where: '$NATIONAL_ID = ?', whereArgs: [user.nationalId]);
    var res = await dbClient.rawQuery(
        'UPDATE Customer SET $NAME = ${user.name}, $FAMILY = ${user.family}, $BIRTHDAY = ${user.birthday}, $MOBILE = ${user.mobile}, $NATIONAL_ID = ${user.nationalId} WHERE id = ${user.id}');

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return new User.fromMap(res.first);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and this is my screen :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../models/user.dart';
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/data/storage/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:atlas_gen_demo/screens/users_list_screen.dart';

class CompleteUserInformationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/complete-user-information';

  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final familyController = TextEditingController();
  final nationalIdController = TextEditingController();
  final mobileController = TextEditingController();

  var id;
  var birthday;


  validate(BuildContext ctx) async {
    if (nameController.text != "" &&
        familyController.text != "" &&
        nationalIdController.text != "" &&
        mobileController.text != "") {
      final dbHelper = DBHelper();
      print("useriddd: $id   birthdayyyy: ${birthday.toString()}");
      User user = await dbHelper.update(User(
          id,
          nameController.text,
          familyController.text,
          null,
          null,
          birthday,
          mobileController.text,
          nationalIdController.text));
      if (user.username != "") {
        navigateToUsersList(ctx);
      }
    } else {
  //     showFlushBar(ctx, "fault", "fill all fields");
    }
  }

  void navigateToUsersList(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      UsersListScreen.routeName,
    );
  }

  void showFlushBar(BuildContext context, String title, String text) {
    Flushbar(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      borderRadius: 8,
      backgroundGradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.purple.shade800, Colors.purpleAccent.shade700],
        stops: [0.6, 1],
      ),
      boxShadows: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black,
          offset: Offset(3, 3),
          blurRadius: 3,
        )
      ],
      dismissDirection: FlushbarDismissDirection.HORIZONTAL,
      forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
      titleText: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mainBold', color: Colors.white),
      ),
      messageText: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'mainMedium', color: Colors.white),
      ),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ).show(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userId = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 250,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/complete_profile.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: FadeAnimation(
                    1.8,
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Complete data",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, 1),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'persianBold',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10))
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                            )),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: nameController,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "name",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                            )),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: familyController,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "family",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                            )),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: nationalIdController,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "national code",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                            )),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: mobileController,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              inputFormatters: [
                                WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                              ],
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: "09123456789",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                                  fontFamily: 'persianMedium',
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                                    showTitleActions: true,
                                    minTime: DateTime(1250, 1, 1),
                                    maxTime: DateTime(1450, 12, 31),
                                    onChanged: (date) {
                                  print('change $date');
                                }, onConfirm: (date) {
                                  birthday = date;
                                  print('confirm $date');
                                },
                                    currentTime: DateTime.now(),
                                    locale: LocaleType.en);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'birthday',
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    FadeAnimation(
                      2,
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () => {
                          // print(
                          //     "useriddd: $userId   birthdayyyy: ${birthday.toString()}"),
                          id = userId,
                          validate(context),
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .4),
                                Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .8),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Complete data",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: 'persianBold',
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

after did some change in code I got this error:

`Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
E/flutter (18587): Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
E/flutter (18587):      (near "00": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE User SET name = mehrdad, family = dolat, birthday = 1450-12-31 00:00:00.000, mobile = 0936, nationalId = 001 WHERE id = {id: 1})
E/flutter (18587): #################################################################) sql 'UPDATE User SET name = mehrdad, family = dolat, birthday = 1450-12-31 00:00:00.000, mobile = 0936, nationalId = 001 WHERE id = {id: 1}' args []}`

updated code :

```
  Future<User> update(String id, String name, String family, String birthday,
      String mobile, String nationalId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.rawQuery(
        'UPDATE $USER_TABLE SET $NAME = $name, $FAMILY = $family, $BIRTHDAY = $birthday, $MOBILE = $mobile, $NATIONAL_ID = $nationalId WHERE id = $id');

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return new User.fromMap(res.first);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and in my screen:

```
  dbHelper.update(
          id.toString(),
          nameController.text,
          familyController.text,
          birthday.toString(),
          mobileController.text,
          nationalIdController.text);

      navigateToUsersList(ctx);
```

Edit Number 2:

I think we need just one more step to do this:

I do a new change on update method in database helper:

```
   Future<int> update(String id, String name, String family, String birthday,
      String mobile, String nationalId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE $USER_TABLE SET $NAME = \'$name\', $FAMILY = \'$family\' ,$BIRTHDAY = \'$birthday\', $MOBILE = \'$mobile\' , $NATIONAL_ID = \'$nationalId\' WHERE $ID = ${int.parse(id)}');
  }
```

and when I try to add an Id for where section I got this error :

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
E/flutter (21459): {id: 2}`

but if I hardcoded id for example `where $ID = 2` everything works fine. how I can fix this issue? why {} add beside id? and how I must remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some search and trying I found the solution:

update method in db_helper:

```
  Future<int> update(String id, String name, String family, String birthday,
      String mobile, String nationalId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.rawUpdate(
        'UPDATE $USER_TABLE SET $NAME = \'$name\', $FAMILY = \'$family\' ,$BIRTHDAY = \'$birthday\', $MOBILE = \'$mobile\' , $NATIONAL_ID = \'$nationalId\' WHERE $ID = ${int.parse(id)}');
  }
```

and validate method in Screen:

```
 validate(BuildContext ctx) async {
    if (nameController.text != "" &&
        familyController.text != "" &&
        nationalIdController.text != "" &&
        mobileController.text != "") {
      final dbHelper = DBHelper();

      dbHelper.update(
          id.toString(),
          nameController.text,
          familyController.text,
          birthday.toString(),
          mobileController.text,
          nationalIdController.text);

      navigateToUsersList(ctx);
    } else {
      showFlushBar(ctx, "error", "Please fill all fields");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I used this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b) to implement my Database. There you can find all things you need to interact with your database.

this will work for you, you just need to implement the "toMap" Method in the User class:

```
Future<void> update(User user) async {
    final dbClient = await database;
    var res = await db.update("Customer", user.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [user.id]);
    return res;
  }
```

Comment: I try this one too. it does not work. as I check I can't access db_handler, try to change  but nothing happened: 
` Future<int> update(int id, String name, String family, String birthday,
      String mobile, String nationalId) async {
    var dbClient = await db;

    int updateCount = await dbClient.rawUpdate('''
    UPDATE $USER_TABLE 
    SET $NAME = ?, $FAMILY = ?,
    $BIRTHDAY =?, $MOBILE = ?, $NATIONAL_ID = ? 
    WHERE $ID = ?
    ''', [name, family, birthday, mobile, nationalId, id]);

    if (updateCount > 0) {
      return updateCount;
    }
    return null;
  }`

Comment: I can't send all the user Model to this method. because the username and password fields must not be changed. just another part must change. (id, username, the password must not change)

Comment: Please don't add additional code as comments to an answer. If you have additional clarification to add to your question, please click the edit button below the question, and add it there.

Comment: I added now 2 new edit David. and in the last edit, I think we are close to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to update the table in SQLite DB.

- Here is my table

| id | URL |
| --- | --- |

- **SwiperList** is my table name
- **Id** is primary key with auto incrementation property
- **URL** is simple text value

  ```
   Future<int> update(String id, String url) async {
   final db = await database;
   return await db.rawUpdate(
       'UPDATE SwiperList SET url = $url  WHERE id = ${int.parse(id)}');
  ```

  }

You can implement it according to your requirement.